# strtotime to get first start of this hour

Tags: php

I am using `strtotime("first day of this month", time());` to get the start of the current month, `strtotime("midnight", time());` to get the start of the current day. Now I want to get the start of the current hour.

`strtotime("last hour", time());` gives me the current hour, minus 1.

Looking at the docs, I see that you can build expressions to get the times you want, however, I have tried several and I am stuck. "First sec of this hour" or "first second of this hour" and "this hour" (same as "now") all give me incorrect values.

How would I go about getting the timestamp of the first moment of the current hour using `strtotime`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) instead. You can still work with the same formats as strtotime, but it also gives you an interface to do things strtotime can't.

#### Example:

```
$date = new DateTime(); // Defaults to now.
$date->setTime($date->format('G'), 0); // Current hour, 0 minute, [0 second]
echo $date->format(DateTime::RFC850), "\n";
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

#### Output:

```
Tuesday, 13-Oct-15 02:00:00 UTC
1444701600
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use something like `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:00:00'))`

Comment: Upvoted because simpler and easier to read than DateTime stuff.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there's no way to get the timestamp of the beginning of an hour using a verbal description. Even `"last hour"` is only returning `now() - 3600`.

Your best bet is the following:

```
$iCurrentTimestamp = strtotime("now");
$iStartOfHour = $iCurrentTimestamp - ($iCurrentTimestamp % 3600);
```

Now modulus 3600 will return the seconds after the start of the hour, then just subtract from the current time.

Comment: Nice solution. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

To get the start time of the day

```
$starttime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("midnight"));
```

to current time

```
$endtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```